# REST api error in SharePoint App

Tags: office-365, rest

I need to create new item to list..

```
$.ajax({
        url: appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)" + "/web/lists/getbytitle('NewList')/items?" + "@target='" + hostWebUrl + "'",
        method: "POST",
        data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.NewListListItem' },
        'Title': "TitleVal", 'Name':"Vikash"}),       
        headers: { 
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose" 
           },
        success: function (data) {  
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
             console.log( " xhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText + " //status: " + status + " //Error: "+error );
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

It shows error:-

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The
>   security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted.
>   Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation
>   again."}}}

How to solve this error?

Comment: It seems form digest has been expired on the page. In this case you will have to acquire new form digest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435432/sharepoint-2013-via-rest-api-error-403-forbidden-when-trying-to-create-item

Comment: have you added request digest form to the body?

Comment: No, how to add digest form to the body?

Comment: Check this link: (Your previous question): http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185447/rest-api-page-validation-error-for-sharepoint-app